# Прыгают inline блоки при смене ширины какого-либо из них

Tags: html, frontend, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте.

Собственно, такое дело: нужно как-то сверстать так, чтобы инлайновые блоки не реагировали на изменения других блоков - не прыгали!

Вот я накидал, вроде работает, если переключать по порядку!
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pankov/ohrv8ttc/)

Но если переключаться между 2-м и 5-м, например, блоки между ними прыгают! Как от этого избавиться?

От "обычного" прыгания (оно, кстати, из-за жирности текста становится, т.к. ширина блока тоже увеличивается, и остальные реагируют) избавился блоком `::after`.

Comment: вам точно нужно менять параметры шрифта в активном выделении?

Comment: Ага, так нужно, дизайн!
НО я решил проблему, подсказали, вместо бордера, который особо никак и не влиял, как я думал, подсказали использовать внутреннию тень!
И все заработало, JsFiddle обновил. ))
Спасибо!